# Deserialize Cosmos SQL API query results List for index view in ASP. NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm working on the [ASP.NET Cosmos template](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-dotnet-application).
I change the Model in:

```
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class Richieste
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contact")]
        public  IList<Contact>? Contacts { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="regdate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? RegDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
        public string? Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="note")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string? Note { get; set; }
    }
    public class Contact
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contacttype")]
        public string? ContactType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contactvalue")]
        public string? ContactValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My data Model in JSON is:

```
{
"id": "a8e33584-3d67-4b11-a4a0-a7c463cbe0c9",
"name": "TestName",
"contact": [
    {
        "contacttype": "11",
        "contactvalue": "111"
    },
    {
        "contacttype": "22",
        "contactvalue": "222"
    },
    {
        "contacttype": "33",
        "contactvalue": "333"
    }
],
"regdate": "2022-10-01T08:30:18.8071788+02:00",
"description": "testDescription",
"note": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."}
```

My services for index view are:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Richieste>> GetItemsAsync(string queryString)
    {
        var query = this._container.GetItemQueryIterator<Richieste>(new QueryDefinition(queryString));
        List<Richieste> results = new List<Richieste>();

        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await query.ReadNextAsync();

            results.AddRange(response.ToList());
        }

        return results;
    }
```

and my controller is:

```
        // GET: RichiesteController
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.GetItemsAsync("SELECT * FROM c"));
    }
```

When I call the Index method in Controller I receive a json deserialization error.

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[CIS5.Models.Contact]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path '[44].contact.contacttype', line 1, position 15982.

How should I deserialize my model?

I try to modify the `GetItemsAsync` service:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Richieste>> GetItemsAsync(string queryString)
    {
        var query = this._container.GetItemQueryIterator<Richieste>(new QueryDefinition(queryString));
        List<Richieste> results = new List<Richieste>();

        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await query.ReadNextAsync();

            results.AddRange(response.ToList());
        }
          var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Richieste>>(results);

        return obj;
    }
```

But it doesn't run, the error is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to my question.

After reading more then a lot about Cosmos DB and No-SQL DB, I finally understand that the Model is the key to almost everything happens with Cosmos DB working App.
I put a IList as subdocument in my model but it was just a sub-document so I modified my model in the row where:

```
public IList<Contact> Contacts { get; Set; }
```

with the correct notation for my issue

```
public Contact[] Contacts { get; Set; }
```

I remove the unuseful line code from services:

```
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Richieste>>(results);
```

and everything runs.

Thank you everyone whos read my post and I'm sorry if my question was so simple.